# What is security is used in the IBM Watson Java SDK between my app and the APIs?

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

We use IBM-Watson java SDK. What kind of security is there between my client and the Watson services?

For example:

- I assume HTTPS is used for outbound
- TLS 1.2?
- strong cyphers (list supported)
- verifying certificates

Answer (score 2):

The IBM Watson Java-SDK uses [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) for HTTP/WebSockets requests. Therefore, the security between Watson and your application is managed by that dependency.

You can read more about the security features in `OkHttp` [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS).

Comment: Thanks German. Is it possible to get the corresponding okHttp object used for the connection to the Watson service to query it for specifically what security was established after negotiation between client and server? That is important for security audits.

Comment: It depends if your app is an Android app or not and which version of the SDK you are using. The latest version (`3.4.0`)  uses OkHttp 3.3.1. During a normal call to Watson. I think with Watson you have TLS 1.2

Comment: Just a regular Java app. I haven't looked through the Okhttp docs, but I suspect if one can get the connection object one can query it to determine what was used. For example: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Connection.html#handshake--

Comment: You can get the code from the SDK and run one of the tests using the `okhttp-logging-interceptor` everything is there.

Comment: It looks like I can create a logging interceptor, but I need to add that to the okhttp client build statement, which is private. I was hoping for a way that didn't involve altering the code (so we don't end up having to maintain our own branch). Unless I am missing something...

Comment: You were interested in knowing what cyphers and TLS is okhttp using in the IBM Watson java-sdk. Well, I think you can do that by modifying a local version of the SDK.